# SaaS with exposed SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

For a client I'm going to deliver a SaaS solution, SaaS in that matter it's still closed to a limited clients that has to sign a contract with us, so not shared world wide and the client base will be around 5-10 companies.

Our first client, the pilot client so to speak, has it as a requirement that they can perform SQL queries (read mode only) on the data, so they can make analysis in Excel along with what our application serves.

My question is that I would for maintain reasons prefer to serve everything in the same codebase, but I'm wondering how I can make sure, clients can access other clients SQL records?

I'm using Laravel so the solution for different installations would be to make everything in maintainable packages and upgrade all installations from there, but this can grow to a lot of work.

How to have the solution with only one solution I'm still not sure, maybe it is to have a separate database per client? That would require a central database to point them to the right database of course, or maybe only have some of the tables in another database, but it already sounds like a mess to me

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel it is possible to have [multiple database connections](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections). As such your thoughts on giving the clients thier own database is going to be the most secure option.

Have your default database be your main application database which will be settings/auth etc.

For each client store their personal data in a separate database per client and **only allow them to query this database**.

Although I don't know the specifics of your application my true suggestion is to avoid the SQL queries completely and build an API.

Your SaaS clients should not have to be concerned with the internal implementation of your database structure. A well built API gives you freedom to modify the database as needed and the SaaS client the peace of mind that their "interface" is not in a technically permanent state of flux.

Comment: Does Excel supports such an API? Their concern is they query their current database from Excel now and don't like to have to change too much about that.

Comment: @EmilMoe I wasn't even aware you could query a database from Excel - but yes you can [query an API from Excel](http://www.excel2013.info/power-query/connection-api/) or a more generic information set https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-connecting-to-importing-data-c0ad7aec-ff1a-4e48-9c21-dc18a102433f

Comment: What part exactly? I can't find where it says about a data layer API